# Telegram shows contacts from different phone?

Tags: contacts, telegram

Recently I installed Telegram on my SGS3 and surprisingly the Telegram contacts show me the contacts from my father's phone!!!! My father has an SGS2.

By the way, on my SGS3 the "Contacts to Display" option is set to show 'Gmail account', and none of my father's lists are there.

Who can explain this?

Comment: Same problem here. Telegram is showing contacts from an older google account that was delete from the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have both google accounts (yours and your father's) synched with your phone OR you are  running Telegram with the same phone numbers.

Comment: Both of us have different gamil account and my father didn't install Telegram on his mobile. Regards